# I'm having huge Rails log is it normal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I'm having a huge rails application log. is it normal ?' 
768 megs for the production log !!

```
root@demo3:/home/canvas/canvas/log# ls -lh
total 960M
-rw-r--r-- 1 canvas canvas 192M Sep 28 12:37 delayed_job.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 canvas canvas  265 Sep 22 08:57 development.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 canvas canvas 910K Sep 28 12:36 newrelic_agent.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 canvas canvas 768M Sep 28 12:37 production.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    26K Sep 28 11:00 super_delayed_job_err.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   113K Sep 22 14:07 super_delayed_job.log
```

Snippet from the log file:
    [- 1e1f92f0-293e-0132-2906-00163c067c2e] Cache hit: _account_lookup2/1 ({})
    [- 1e1f92f0-293e-0132-2906-00163c067c2e] Cache hit: settings_for_plugin2/sessions ({})
    [- 208bd370-293e-0132-2906-00163c067c2e]

```
Processing UsersController#user_dashboard (for 54.248.250.232 at 2014-09-28 14:06:04) [GET]
[- 208bd370-293e-0132-2906-00163c067c2e]   Parameters: {"controller"=>"users",    "action"=>"user_dashboard"}
[- 208bd370-293e-0132-2906-00163c067c2e] Redirected to http://subdomain.example.com/login
[- 208bd370-293e-0132-2906-00163c067c2e] Filter chain halted as [:require_user]    rendered_or_redirected.
[- 208bd370-293e-0132-2906-00163c067c2e] Completed in 3ms (DB: 0) | 302 Found          [http://demo3.iqraalms.com/]
[- 208bd370-293e-0132-2906-00163c067c2e] [STAT] 903612 903612 0 903612 0.010000000000000231 0
```

Any idea how to optimise it ?

Comment: Well, if your app gets traffic, it's perfectly normal for the log to grow very big. You should use the `logrotate` utility so your logs get rotated daily or weekly, depending on you needs. http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate

Answer (score 1):

You could raise the log level to get less data (warn, error or fatal) in your config file as described in [rails guide on debugging](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels). Or as sjaime pointed out in his comment, [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) is a utility that will solve this problem for you (compress your log every day/week/month or when it reaches a certain size, delete/email/keep old archives, ...).

One thing that will blow up your log tremendously are for example asset errors (missing fonts is a classic there). Make sure you have non of these. Other than that, with log level info and a couple of users on your site, your log will grow quickly.